# if the comparison of two columns is true, then compare their corresponding value in the next two columns and report true/false

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Can't seem to get this one. I am comparing in excel if 2 columns (**A** and **H**) have any matching document #'s with

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(H3,$A:$A,1,FALSE)))
```

If this returns `TRUE`, I want to compare the revision # corresponding to each document # and return `TRUE` or `FALSE` as well. I have the first `VLOOKUP` working correctly but now I'm unsure how to use a nested if and be sure it is extracting the corresponding revision #. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

*So basically it is an If true, then if true....

*Comparing column A with column H. if there is a matching document #, I want to compare their corresponding revisions (revisions for column A are in column B and revisions for column H are in column E) and see if those ALSO match.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQrLE.png) THANK YOU for your swift responses!!!

*sorry I need 2 more reputations to add an image apparently...

*[image: excel file image description just above!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps COUNTIFS will give you your answer

> =COUNTIFS(A:A,H3,B:B,E3)>0

That will give you TRUE only if document H3 is found in column A...and on that same row the revision # in column B is the same as E3

Comment: hmmm I tried that but doesn't seem to work. It is just outputting the same as my previous vlookup formula but not working for the corresponding rev comparison.

Comment: OK, perhaps I am misinterpreting what you need - in the question you say "if there is a matching document #, I want to compare their corresponding revisions" - can you be specific about that? In my formula I'm matching H3 against column A, and assuming that "their corresponding revisions" means E3, is that wrong. Can you give an example, what if H3 matches A10, what's the next comparison you need to do specifically?

Comment: Thank you for your response and I apologize for the confusion. Column E refers to the revision for corresponding column H (E3 is for H3), and column B refers to the revision for corresponding column B (B3 is for A3). So if H3 matches A50 (doc#), I want to check if E3 also matches B50 (rev#).

Comment: ....in that case I think my suggested formula should work OK. It only returns TRUE if there is at least one row in the data where H3 matches the column A value and E3 matches the corresponding column B value - in your example if H3 matches A50 and E3 **doesn't** match B50 then you'd get FALSE

Comment: Ok, thank you I understand your formula now and have verified it works. Thanks again everyone for your help.

Comment: Barry can you please explain your COUNTIFS formula above? What does the >0 mean exactly? I found some cases where a document didn't have a rev number associated with it and it said TRUE for the formula, which isn't accurate for some of them.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interested to get more info from OP, but for now this might be a better way to avoid using the combo of `NOT`, `ISNA` and `VLOOKUP` all together:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A=H3)),[True Code],[False Code])
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, it seems to me that the second condition implies a SUMPRODUCT formula with two conditions....or COUNTIFS to do the same, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what the columns you're working with are like but this is how you would add the nested if:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(H3,$A:$A,1,FALSE))),[True Code],[False Code])
```

If you can provide a better idea of the column layouts (like a picture?) I can elaborate.

Comparing column A with column H (just off screen). 
If there is a matching document #, I want to compare their corresponding revisions (revisions for column A are in column B and revisions for column H are in column E) and see if those ALSO match.

[Image]